# iOS NSURLSessionConfiguration without Caching not working as intended

Tags: ios, security, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

i am facing a security issue in iOS7. I want to make my url connection without any caching by doing the following configuration:

```
+(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)createSessionConfig {

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig =
    [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];

    sessionConfig.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
    sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0;
    sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60.0;
    sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10;
    sessionConfig.URLCache = nil;
    sessionConfig.URLCredentialStorage = nil;
    sessionConfig.HTTPCookieStorage = nil;

    return sessionConfig;
}
```

When i run a NSURLSessionDataTask there is still the file Cache.db-wal created on the file system with the entries.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue ? I want to have no entries in the cache file on the file system.

BR,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something very similar. Instead of setting up the configuration instance as an ephemeral session I used `defaultSessionConfiguration`. The ephemeral session caches into RAM rather than the disk. So by setting all of the different persistent caching properties to nil and using the default session it worked as I needed it.